# string to char conversion by atoi from a defined index

Tags: c, linux, atoi

Let's say I have `char x[3] = "123";` and I would like to convert only index 1 and index2 "`23`" of the char array, can I do it by `atoi`?

I know I can do it by `char z[2]; z[0]=x[1]; z[1]=x[2]; atoi(z);` but it is not what I am asking for.

Comment: `char x[3] = "123";` is not valid, as you need `[4]` to leave space for the NUL-terminator.

Comment: @abelenky It's valid, it's the same as `char x[] = { '1', '2', '3' };`. Using that where a 0-terminated character array is expected is of course wrong (will typically invoke UB).

Comment: @DanielFischer: Invoking UB, including nasal demons, is a strange understanding of "valid".  Typically UB and invalid are interchangable.  (Unless you enjoy nasal demons).

Comment: @abelenky `char x[3] = "123";` is perfectly valid if you treat it as an array of 3 `char`. When you change its contents to include a 0 byte, you can even use it as a 0-terminated character array. Character arrays aren't the only things that when used inappropriately invoke UB. Yes, something like `char x[3] = "123";` is _wrong_ most of the times it's written, but it's perfectly valid C. The behaviour of that is defined by the standard. It's not the declaration and initialisation that are invalid, it's the use (I'm convinced that's what you meant, but it ain't what you wrote ;).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with

```
char x[4];
int i;

strcpy(x, "123");
i = atoi(x + 1);
```

Because `x` is a pointer to char, `x + 1` is a pointer to the next char.  If you try to print with

```
printf("%s", x + 1);
```

You'l get `23` as the output.

Note though that you need to declare the length of the char array to be one more than the number of characters in it - to accommodate the ending `\0`.

Comment: Why not just `atoi("123" + index)` ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan That would also be correct, however most likely the `char*` variable is not static, so it's for demonstration only.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to convert the first digit, then the remaining part of the string, you can do:

```
char x[] = "123";

int first = x[0]-'0';
int rest  = atoi(&x[1]);

printf("Answers are %d and %d\n", first, rest);
```

**Result:**

```
Answers are 1 and 23
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can convert such a "suffix" string by giving `atoi()` a pointer to the first character where you want conversion to start:

```
const int i = atoi(x + 1);
```

Note that this only works for a suffix, since it will always read up to the first `'\0'` termiator character.

Also note, as pointed out in a question comment, that this assumes there *is* a terminator, which your code won't have.

You must have:

```
char x[4] = "123";
```

or just

```
char x[] = "123";
```

or

```
const char *x = "123";
```

To get the terminator to fit. If you don't have a terminated array, it's not a string, and passing a pointer to any part of it to `atoi()` is not valid.

Comment: Well, actually passing a raw char pointer (char *x) to atoi() is also valid. Maybe you intended something different with "terminated array"?